# Gcov not generating.gcda files for few classes

Tags: code-coverage, gcov, test-coverage

I am using gcov to find code coverage of my application while running functional test cases.

Issue: .gcda files are not getting created for few classes though those classes are being executed

Steps:

1. Compile Application code with gcov and verify .gcno files are generated for all classes
2. Create binary image of compiled code and deploy server using that binary
3. Use cross profiling while deploying server. Home directory structure for my source code was "/proj/QQ/scm/tools/jenkins/db_ws/FunctionTestCoverage/ccode/" and I used below mentioned gcov parameters for cross profiling

- GCOV_PREFIX=/automation/testCoverage
- GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP=7

4. Run Functional Test Cases to hit application code
5. **.gcda files gets created for few classes only. It is not getting created for all classes which are being executed.**
6. .gcda files are generating under directory structure "/automation/testCoverage/ccode"

I believe this should not be issue with cross profiling. suppose I have 5 directories in parallel then .gcda files are generating for 2 directories only.

What can be root cause for my issue where .gcda are generating for only few files and how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about your process? When there are no gcda files, that usually indicates that those “classes” were not part of the binary you executed. (Actually, there isn't a gcno/gcda per class but per compilation unit, so roughly per .c or .cpp file). However, since you're running and deploying on *different* servers, there could be additional causes. In particular: does the server have the EXACT SAME paths and directory layout as the system on which you compiled? Otherwise, you must do [cross-profiling](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Cross-profiling.html#Cross-profiling).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am using cross-profiling. I will explain my query with this example. Let's say I have 5 .cpp files in my application. After compilation with gcov, .gcno file got created for all 5 files. Now I created binary image of this compiled code and deployed server with cross-profiling. I ran few functional test cases which hit code in 4 out of 5 classes but .gcda file is generating for only 2 classes. The issue is why .gcda file is not generating for all 4 classes which got executed during test run.

Comment: Could you maybe [edit] the question to provide more details on your cross-profiling setup? What directory structure do you have, what are your GCOV_PREFIX and GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP settings?